# How to integrate Laravel with Nuxt js

Tags: php, laravel, nuxt.js, laravel-6.2, laravel-api

As I am using Laravel as Backend and Nuxt js as Frontend I'm not able to use both together and also I'm not able to call any API from the frontend.

So please help me if anyone knew about it.

As I am using the below details for creating a project but I am not able to call any API in Nuxt js even though writing code in `api.php` route file and creating a respected controller and model.

> 1. Create a fresh project

```
`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel <PROJECT NAME>`
```

> 2. Now move to a respected directory using below command

```
`cd <PROJECT NAME>`
```

> 3. Give permission to a storage folder on the root folder of the project

```
`sudo chmod -R 777 storage/`
```

> 4. Create a database
> 5. update .env
> 6. Config Clear

`php artisan config:clear`

> 7. Storage Link

`php artisan storage::link`

> 8. Install Passport

`composer require laravel/passport`

> 9. Create database structure by using a below command on the ROOT folder of the project

`php artisan migrate`

> 10. For initial records, Please using below command

`php artisan db:seed`

> 11. Install NPM

`npm install`

> 12. Now install nuxt js

`npx create-nuxt-app <PROJECT NAME>`

> 13. Now move to a respected directory using below command

`cd <PROJECT NAME>`

> 14. To start the project we need to run below command

`npm run build` | `npm run start` /  `npm run dev`

Comment: I use [laravel nuxt starter](https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-nuxt) which is pretty good. You can also do like `composer create-project --prefer-dist cretueusebiu/laravel-nuxt` directly

Comment: Is your laravel app running? I do not see `php artisan serve` anywhere in your post. If the application is running, I would suggest using Postman in the first place to check the API is working properly before starting your SPA development.

Answer (score 1):

first check your `package.json` file and in your `dependencies` see do you have `@nuxtjs/axios` or not?
if no go to [https://axios.nuxtjs.org](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/) and install it

also in same file in `devDependencies` check that you have `@nuxt/typescript-build` and if you don't go to [https://typescript.nuxtjs.org](https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/) and install it too

after that you can simply use `$axios` to send and get api request

a sample code for that is:

```
async asyncData({ $axios }) {
  const test = await $axios.$get('your address')
  return { test }
}
```

more information can found in https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage

Answer (score 1):

i had this experience too . but i choose handle project separately because of NUXT have a lot of dependecies and options , laravel too !
so you can run server side by laravel like as Database logic Controller and ETC
and make something amazing with NUXT in client-side -
and you can connect nuxt and laravel with axios service for SPA(single-page-application)
or api and web.php in laravel service for normally sites . good luck

Comment: Your answer does not provide any help to OP's specific problem.